# How to combine all documents' field of array together in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How to combine the field of the array of all documents together in MongoDB?

For example:

My collection contains these documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: 0,
    categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    categories: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    categories: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  },
];
```

And the result must be:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Comment: `data.flatMap` is a good place to start

Comment: As you can see, we do not know if you want a JavaScript or a Mongo solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

```
db.collection.distinct('categories')
```

If the results are more than 16mb then you can only use `$unwind` and `$group` in an aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$categories"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$categories"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Your aggregate query doesn't return the desired output: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AQxgSq4VEDD)

Comment: you can't get the exact output with the aggregation pipeline because it returns an array of objects by definition.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but OP expects a string array, not an object array.

Comment: he didnt say i think that he wants unique results

Answer (score 1):

You can `$unwind` and `$group` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$categories"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "categories": {
        "$push": "$categories"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-yVO2n55ZPR)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about JS, I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
const res = [
  {
    _id: 0,
    categories: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    categories: ['d', 'e', 'f'],
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    categories: ['g', 'h', 'i'],
  },
].reduce((acc, current) => ([...acc, ...current.categories]), [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const list = [
    {
      _id: 0,
      categories: ["a", "b", "c"],
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      categories: ["d", "e", "f"],
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      categories: ["g", "h", "i"],
    },
  ];
  let newList = list.map((item) => [...item.categories]);
  let finalList = newList.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b]);
```

first make a new containing all the categories lists from your list. Then use a reducer like shown with the help of spread operators to get them separated

Answer (score 1):

Bellow are 2 ways to do it, without removing duplicates, because i think you want all values.

Query (JF solution is better than this, but this is alternative way)
(Both queries work if categories final array < 16MB)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GenELsb0qEi)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "categories": {
        "$push": "$categories"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "categories": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$categories",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Returns

```js
[
  {
    "categories": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
      "d",
      "e",
      "f",
      "g",
      "h",
      "i"
    ]
  }
]
```

Query2
(if categories > 16 MB)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y62qx9wwc4D)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$categories"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "_id"
    ]
  }
])
```

Returns

```js
[
  {
    "categories": "a"
  },
  {
    "categories": "b"
  },
  {
    "categories": "c"
  },
  {
    "categories": "d"
  },
  {
    "categories": "e"
  },
  {
    "categories": "f"
  },
  {
    "categories": "g"
  },
  {
    "categories": "h"
  },
  {
    "categories": "i"
  }
]
```